# Problems aggregating data by variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I have data that looks like this:

```
ID  FileSource      Age MamUlt  ProcDate    Name
223 Facility        35  M       19591       SWEDISH
223 Facility        35  M       19592       SWEDISH
223 Facility        35  U       19592       SWEDISH
223 Facility        35  U       19593       SWEDISH
223 Non-Facility    35  M       19594       RADIA
223 Non-Facility    35  U       19594       RADIA
```

What I am trying to do is to combine that data (for each ID in the data set) to look like this:

```
ID   Age MAMs ULTs SameDate 
223  35  3    3    2
```

So, for each ID, I need the total times "M" and "U" show up and how many times they show up on the same date; twice in this sample.

Here is what I have so far:

```
data ImageTotals;
    set ImageClaims;
    by ID;
    retain ID MAMs ULTs SameDate;

    if first.ID then do;
        MAMs = 0;
        ULTs = 0;
        MamDate = .;
        UltDate = .;
        SameDate = 0;
    end;

    if MamUlt = "M" then do; MAMs = MAMs + 1; MamDate = ProcDate; end;
    if MamUlt = "U" then do; ULTs = ULTs + 1; UltDate = ProcDate; end;
    if MamDate = UltDate and MamDate ^= . then do; SameDate = SameDate+1; end;

    if last.ID;
    keep ID MAMs ULTs SameDate;
run;
```

Any advice? This solves the count problems but not the SameDate problem (still coming up as zero for this instance).

Comment: Please post any code you've tried.

Comment: Please describe more of the logic for SameDate.  What does it mean for there to be a match between MAMdate and ULTdate?  Does match mean that for a single value of ID-FileSource-Age-Name there is a MAM record and and ULT record with the same date?   THis is an odd data format.  Might be easier if you change it to have columns for ID FileSource Age Name Procedure ProcedureDate.  The value of Procedure would me "MAM" or "ULT"

Comment: That's a good idea, will do that.As to what to count, I need to count  the number of times an ULT and MAM occurred an the same date for each ID. Updating question now.

Comment: I added an answer, but for your sample data, I think the DATA step code you have will give the correct result for SAMEDATE if you add MamDate and UltDate to your retain statement.   If the real data could have more than one mammogram or ultrasound record on the same date, this might not work correctly.  This relies on fact that data are sorted by ID and ProcDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is probably a SQL problem (not my specialty), but since you started on a DATA step solution I took a stab at both.  I also added more test data.

```
data ImageClaims;
  input id age Proc $1. ProcDate;
  cards;
223 35 M 19591
223 35 M 19592
223 35 U 19592
223 35 U 19593
223 35 M 19594
223 35 U 19594
224 35 M 19591
224 35 M 19592
224 35 M 19593
224 35 M 19593
224 35 M 19594
224 35 U 19595
225 35 M 19592
225 35 U 19592
225 35 U 19593
225 35 M 19593
225 35 M 19594
225 35 U 19594
;
run;
```

For DATA step approach, create counters for MAMs, ULTs, and MAMULTs (Mam and Ult on same day).  Note because I use sum statement for these counters (MAMs++1) they are implicitly retained.

```
data ImageTotals (keep=id Age MAMs ULTs MAMULTs);
  set ImageClaims;
  by ID ProcDate;
  retain HaveMam HaveUlt; *Count vars are implicitly retained by sum statement;
  if first.ID then do;
    MAMs=0;    *count of mammograms;
    ULTs=0;    *count of ultrasounds;
    MAMULTs=0; *count of mammograms and ultrasounds on same date;
  end;
  if first.ProcDate then do;
    HaveMam=0;  *indicator for have a mammogram or not on that date;
    HaveUlt=0;  *indicator for have an ultrasound or not on that date;
  end;

  if Proc='M' then do;
    HaveMam=1;  *set mammogram indicator (for that date);
    MAMs++1;    *increment counter;
  end;
  else if Proc='U' then do;
    HaveUlt=1;  *set ultrasound indicator (for that date);
    ULTs++1;    *increment counter;
  end;

  if last.ProcDate then do;
    MAMULTs++(HaveMam=1 and HaveUlt=1); *increment MamUlts counter if had both on same date;
  end;

  if last.id;
run;
```

For SQL solution I use a subquery that counts MAMs, ULTs, and MAMULTs by ID and ProcDate, and an outer query then sums these by ID.  Probably there's a better SQL solution, but I think this works.

```
proc sql;
  create table ImageTotals as
    select id
          ,max(age) as age  /*arbitrary use of max age is constant within id*/
          ,sum(MAMs) as MAMs
          ,sum(ULTs) as ULTs
          ,sum(MAMULTs) as MAMULTs
    from (
          select id
                ,procdate
                ,max(age) as age
                ,sum(Proc='M') as MAMs
                ,sum(Proc='U') as ULTs
                ,count(distinct(Proc))=2 as MAMULTs
          from ImageClaims
          group by id,ProcDate
          )
    group by id
  ;
quit;

proc print;
run;
```

Work.ImageTotals I get from both steps is:

```
Obs     id    age    MAMs    ULTs    MAMULTs

 1     223     35      3       3        2
 2     224     35      5       1        0
 3     225     35      3       3        3
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. SQL solution says "Summary functions nested this way are not supported", but after renaming some variables I was able to get the DATA step to work. Thanks, you saved my butt here.

Comment: Interesting, the SQL runs fine for me.  Yes, I had renamed your MAMULT column to PROC.  Glad it helped.  Take a look at @Tom's answer as well.  The DOW loop he used is a more complex  approach (well, arguably less complex, but requires a deeper understanding of the DATA step), and is a great tool to add to your tool box.  I voted for his answer, not mine. : )

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOW loop to do the aggregation in a data step.  Data must be sorted by ID and PROCDATE.  Within the same date count how many times M or U appear. Then you can use those day counts to aggregate at the ID level and also test if both appeared on the same date.  The AGE variable is simply kept so it will have the value from the last record for that ID.

```
data counts ;
  do until (last.id);
    m=0;
    u=0;
    do until (last.procdate);
      set imageclaims;
      by id procdate;
      m= sum(m,proc='M');
      u= sum(u,proc='U');
    end;
    MAMs=sum(mams,m);
    ULTs=sum(ults,u);
    SameDate=sum(samedate,m and u);
  end;
  keep id age mams ults samedate ;
run;
```

Comment: Great work, thanks very much. It is very clear to see exactly how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking this could be solved with proc sql (count/group by) once you take Q's suggestion, unless I am misinterpreting the complexity here...was going to post some code, but will let you take a crack at it first...

Comment: This is a useful suggestion, but it's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Correct, but i didnt have enough "rep" to comment...but glad i had the right concept...just wanted to stear him in a good direction.